# Formatar data e valor monetário para salvar no banco de dados

Tags: php, csv

Estou extraindo dados de um arquivo `.xlsx`. convertendo-os em `.csv` e exibindo na tela. Até aqui tudo bem, porém, quero jogar esses dados em um banco de dados, usando PHP, mas para isso preciso converter os dados, pois do jeito que estão, não vão entrar no banco, vejam:

```
10-01-15 SAI 87,059.56 UVA SAFRA 2015 - APB
```

Preciso formatar a data `10-01-15` e o valor `87,059.56`, o resto dos dados é tranquilo. sai - `UVA SAFRA 2015 - APB`

Será que eu teria que jogar assim mesmo no banco, e depois pegar eles, converter a data e o valor e jogar em outra tabela?

Segue o código:

```
if (isset($_POST['pega'])) {

include_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");

$uploadDir = "uploadFile/";

$uploadfile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo pego com sucesso";
    echo "<br><br>";
}else{
    echo "Não foi possível pegar arquivo";
    echo "<br><br>";
}

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($uploadfile);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$csvFileName = str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $uploadfile);
$objWriter->save($csvFileName);
if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c]." ";
        }
        echo "<br />\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
}
```

Consegui separar os dados, mas não consigo jogar pro banco, estou usando isso:

```
        $pdo = conectar();
        $insereDados=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dadosImportados (data, tipo, valor, descricao) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $insereDados->bindValue(0, $data[0]); 
        $insereDados->bindValue(1, $data[1]); 
        $insereDados->bindValue(2, $data[2]); 
        $insereDados->bindValue(3, $data[3]); 

        $insereDados->execute();
```

Mas essa mensagem aparece na tela:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importa/importaArquivo.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importa/importaArquivo.php(68): PDOStatement->bindValue(0, '10-01-15') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importa/importaArquivo.php on line 68"

Comment: Formatar a data para o formato `YYYY-DD-MM` ? Qual o tipo de coluna que vai guardar o valor monetário?

Comment: Coloca o código que você usa para pegar o xlsx e jogar na tela. Vai ajudar a chegar a uma sugestão.

Comment: `10-01-15 SAI 87,059.56 UVA SAFRA 2015 - APB` isso vem como um valor do csv? será aquela virgula depois do 87 não atrapalha?

Comment: Sim, aaaa-dd-mm, a coluna será do tipo Date

Comment: Não, cada dado vem em um valor do array
echo $data[$c]." ";

Comment: Ele gera um .csv, mas está sendo exibido na tela os dados Becco.

Comment: Deletei o comment de cima, agora que você postou o código ficou melhor a pergunta.

Comment: A dúvida em si é basicamente como formatar a data e o valor monetário? ASsim, todo o restante é desnecessário.. Ou tem algo a mais que isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Daniel Omine... Na verdade os outros dados não são desnecessários, mas a data e o valor, devem ser ajustados para ir pro banco.

Comment: Alguma idea pessoal?

Comment: eu quis dizer que no contexto da pergunta foi desnecessário colocar tantos detalhes.. Bastaria somente perguntar como formartar data e moeda.

Comment: Nossa cara! Tem uns que dizem pra detalhar, especificar melhor a pergunta e agora vc diz que não é necessário.

Comment: Deve ter bom senso em discernir o que é "detalhar uma pergunta". Coloque apenas o que é essencial. No seu caso, por exemplo, Você quer saber somente como formatar a data e a moeda. Por isso, todo o restante que não tem relação com isso, é fora de contexto. Mas também não basta só pedir e ficar esperando. Recomendo mostrar também o que vc tentou fazer para resolver pois isso aqui não é centro de suporte técnico gratuito onde joga-se os códigos e, num toque de mágica surgem soluções.

Comment: Você pode escolher uma resposta correta?

Comment: as respostas não te ajudaram? se não ajudaram, o que está faltando para ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

**Sua pergunta foi:**

> Será que eu teria que jogar assim mesmo no banco, e depois pegar eles,
>   converter a data e o valor e jogar em outra tabela?

Transforme seus dados da forma como desejas e após isso é que deve jogá-los no seu banco. Não deves passar essa responsabilidade para o banco, pois ele já tem outras responsabilidades. Trate os dados e jogue para teu banco uma vez somente, sem vai e vem de tabela. Trate os dados antes, e depois salve-os.

Comment: Realmente seria legal levar tudo para o banco em uma tabela temporaria depois faz a tratativa e coloca na tabela final.

Comment: Pois durtto, mas como eu poderia tratar essa data 10-01-15 e esse valor  87,059.56? Pois eles estão vindo em um array e está complicado de pegar eles e tratar.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que a data original está no formato dd-mm-yy (dia, mês e ano com 2 dígitos), cujo ano seja dentro do [século 21](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9culo_XXI) (2001~2100) e, também considerando que esteja usando banco de dados MySQL, a string deve ser formato no padrão [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
$str = '10-01-15';
$arr = explode('-', $str);
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
echo '20'.implode('-', $arr); // Resulta em 2015-01-10
```

Caso o tipo da coluna no banco de dados seja `datetime`, adicione o tempo.

Como não há especificação do tempo no código que postou na pergunta original, pode adicionar o tempo com zero.

```
echo '20'.implode('-', $arr).' 00:00:00'; // Resultará em 2015-01-10 00:00:00
```

Para a moeda, depende como está definida a coluna no banco de dados. A recomendação é o tipo `decimal(14,6)`, mesmo que trabalhe com moedas de valor inteiro e independente do formato visual apresentar valores decimais com 2 casas.

```
$str = '87,059.56';
echo str_replace(',', '', $str); // Resulta em 87059.56
```

Caso defina a coluna do banco de dados como `decimal(14,6)`, o valor será salvo como `87059.560000`.

Quando fizer a leitura dessa coluna, para apresentar com 2 casas e formatada com vírgula, no padrão visual do Brasil, utilize a função [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format('87059.560000', 2, ',', '.'); // Resulta em 87.059,56
```

Note que não adaptei a resposta ao código postado na pergunta pois isso é o seu trabalho.

Aqui você tem a informação necessária para prosseguir e implementar para o seu caso ou usar para outros casos diversos.

Comment: Daniel, o tipo de dado para a data será Date, e o valor Decimal(12,2). Não tem mistério.
E desculpe, mas achei bem complexa sua explicação hehehe
Outra coisa, é um pouco mais complicado, pois todos os dados estão sendo impressos nesse:

for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c]." ";
        }

Comment: -1 pela "turminha que dá negativo a esmo" :p Senti falta do ++1 do AP pela resposta detalhada :)

Comment: +1 pela boa resposta.